# In opera, element.tagName has no method toUpperCase

Tags: javascript, html, dom, opera

To check if proper DOM element was passed to a function, I can use two methods:

1. Check the instance (does not work in IE):

   ```
   if(element instanceof HTMLInputElement)
   ```
2. Check the tagName property. This can be either `input` or `INPUT` depending on document doctype. This is why I use `.toUpperCase` method.

   ```
    if(input.tagName.toUpperCase()=="INPUT")
   ```

So am I doing something wrong, or should I just stick to OR between my two options, like this:

```
input.tagName!=null&&input.tagName.toUpperCase!=null&&input.tagName.toUpperCase()=="INPUT"
||
input instanceof HTMLInputElement
```

Comment: what do you get if you do a `console.log(input.tagName)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be some problem with your code. This works perfect in opera:

http://jsfiddle.net/sW7WB/

HTML

```
<input id="test" type="text" value"hello">
<div id="result"></div>
```

JS

```
var element = document.getElementById('test');
var result =  document.getElementById('result');
result.innerHTML = element.tagName.toUpperCase();
```

RESULT

```
INPUT
```

Maybe you aren't selecting the element properly. Are you sure you are executing your script when the page is loaded?